# Fail to load values in textboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have textboxes which is placed inside accordian (ajax control).In pageload event i have written the code to load values in textboxes. But onload  event one error is coming as object not set to instance of a object. Values are not coming in textboxes.
Then i tried to initialize controls in textboxes .Then the error cleared. But
Values are not coming in textboxes. What may be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you post your aspx code and what you do in codebehind? We can start guessing, but there can be 100 solutions to your question as it is...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the properties of the Accordian properly?

If yes, check the values which you are assigning to the textbox. If they are blank, the values won't be visible.

Try giving a hardcoded value to your textbox and check if it appears or not -

```
textboxObject.Text = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: i have tried this.But error is coming as object not set to instance of an object .What property i have to set in accordian.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, as the Textbox is a child control of the accordian you possible have to use the AccordianObject.FindControl() method to find your textbox.

More information or posting some code would help, otherwise we are just going to be taking stabs in the dark.